# javascript on nodejs represent timestamp in a 4 bytes array

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, timestamp

In order to work with an external API, I need to store in a 4 bytes array the current timestamp.
I saw in their examples that the array should look for example:

> [97, 91, 43, 83] // timestamp

How did they get to the above numbers? and how can I save in javascript (es6) with node.js the current timestamp into a 4 bytes array?

Comment: What is the resolution of the timestamp? (milliseconds?). Which timestamp does the example represent? Do you have more examples of pairs of timestamps and 4-bytes equivalent?

Comment: it represents 1633364819 timestamp - so it seems to me in seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common timestamp metric is [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). The time I write this, the unix time is 1652213764, which in hexadecimal is `62 7a c8 04`, which indeed can be represented with 4 bytes. The equivalent in decimal bytes is `98 122 200 4`.

How to do this in JavaScript:

```js
function timeStampBytes(timestamp) {
    const res = new Uint8Array(4);
    res[0] = timestamp >> 24;
    res[1] = (timestamp >> 16) & 0xff;
    res[2] = (timestamp >> 8) & 0xff;
    res[3] = timestamp & 0xff;
    return res;
}

let timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000); // Unix time
console.log("timestamp: ", timestamp);
console.log("timestamp in HEX: ", timestamp.toString(16));
console.log("timestamp in bytes array: ", ...timeStampBytes(timestamp));
```

Comment: extra point for printing the array with ...